# Propriedade instanciada pelo Castle sendo gravada em Banco de Dados como Proxy

Tags: c#, castle-windsor

Tenho um sistema de Log que Compara duas classes genéricas e escreve o nome da propriedade e o valor dela, em uma coluna do meu banco de dados.

Quando a propriedade é do tipo string, int, datetime, etc., é gravado no banco

```
Name:Valor
```

quando a propriedade da classe é uma classe por exemplo:

```
public Ramal Ramal { get; set; }
```

é gravado no banco `Castle.Proxies.RamalProxy`. Gostaria de saber como posso solucionar isso (não gravar o proxy, e sim a classe original).

```
 public class Telefone
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public Ramal Ramal { get; set; }
}

public class Ramal
{
    public string RamalValue { get; set; }
}
```

metodo que separa as propriedades,

```
 public static List<LogMessage> GetUpdateLogList<T>(T objFrom, T objTo, string[] ignore)
    {
        if (objFrom != null && objTo != null)
        {
            var type = typeof(T);
            var ignoreList = new List<string>(ignore);
            var unequalProperties =
                from pi in type.GetProperties(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance)
                where !ignoreList.Contains(pi.Name)
                let propertyName = pi.Name
                let selfValue = type.GetProperty(pi.Name).GetValue(objFrom, null)
                let toValue = type.GetProperty(pi.Name).GetValue(objTo, null)
                where selfValue != toValue && (selfValue == null || !selfValue.Equals(toValue))
                select new LogMessage(propertyName.ToString()
                                        , selfValue == null ? "null" : selfValue.ToString()
                                        , toValue == null ? "null" : toValue.ToString()
                                        );



            List<LogMessage> logsChanged = unequalProperties.ToList();

            return logsChanged;
        }
```

onde objFrom é a classe Original e objTo é a classe modificada(creio que isso não vem ao caso.)

Comment: Dê uma exemplo do que está querendo fazer. Não me parece fazer sentido o que quer, mas talvez seja só por uma questão de terminologia.

Comment: Os comentários não ajudaram nada, tá tudo muito solto, sem contexto. Ainda não parece fazer sentido querer saber isto, mas mostre-nos que faz, editando a pergunta e colocando algo mais concreto que demonstre a necessidade. Talvez a solução seja outra. Ou nem precise disto. Assim evitará que a pergunta seja fechada por não estar clara.

Comment: Um monte de gente demonstrou interesse em te ajudar. Capricha mais nessa pergunta aí.

Comment: Você disse que está usando o Castle. A pergunta deveria ser em como resolver uma propriedade que está sendo lida como Proxy.

Comment: Precisamos agora do código que você utiliza para serializar o elemento para o Log. Pode ser que você precisa desenvelopar o objeto que está dentro do proxy.

Answer (score 2):

## Você pode usar o ToString

Ao gravar o valor de qualquer propriedade no banco você usaria o método `ToString()` do valor. Dependendo de como você grava no banco isso já está sendo feito.

Então, quando a propriedade for uma classe sua em vez de ser um valor do .Net, você implementa na sua classe o **ToString** retornando um valor que melhor represente o objeto.

Por exemplo, digamos que a propriedade de um objeto `Ramal` que melhor o represente seja uma chamada *Numero*. A implementação do `ToString` ficaria assim:

```
class Ramal
{
    public String Numero { get; set; }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return Numero;
    }
}
```

Se for chamar o método *ToString* explicitamente, lembre-se de verificar primeiro se o valor da propriedade é diferente de *null* para que você não tenha uma *NullReferenceException*.

Comment: ótimo, funcionou, mas eu teria que fazer isso em todas as minhas classes. O objetivo seria o mas genérico possível.
o componente de Log é uma DLL. seria algo do tipo como um foreach nas classes que eu recebo do método  'GetUpdateLogList'

Comment: Teria que fazer em todas as classes. Se você tem controle sobre todas elas é fácil - vai levar pouco tempo se forem dezenas e muito tempo se forem milhares. Mas é fácil.

Comment: Se você não tem controle sobre todas as classes, pode tentar deduzir qual é a popriedade mais importante. O critério de "mais importante" poderia ser por exemplo a primeira propriedade de um tipo "primitivo" que não seja o *Id* do objeto. Isso funcionou pra mim uma vez mas eu estava lidando com metadados de tabelas em vez de classes - a primeira coluna da tabela que não fosse Id nem chave estangeira era considerada a coluna mais importante. O problema é que pode-se obter as colunas de uma tabela na ordem em que elas foram criadas mas a princípio você não consegue fazer isso usando reflection.